# The number of solutions to the equations $x^2-2y^2=\pm p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Knowing that the two equations $x^2-2y^2=\pm1$ have infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., that there are infinitely many elements with norm $\pm 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$), how does one prove that the two equations $x^2-2y^2=\pm p$ also have infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ for every prime $p$ satisfying $p\equiv_8 \pm 1$?

Comment: By $\equiv_8$ do you mean that $p\equiv\pm 1\bmod8$?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: yes, precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $ K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2}) $. First, observe that if we exhibit only one solution, we automatically have infinitely many solutions. Now, exhibiting a divisor of a prime $ p $ in $ \mathcal O_K $ is the same thing as exhibiting a prime ideal of $ \mathcal O_K $ lying above $ p $, since $ K $ has class number $ 1 $. Hence it suffices to identify the inert primes in $ \mathcal O_K $. Dedekind's factorization criterion tells us that the inert primes are precisely the primes $ p $ such that $ X^2 - 2 $ is irreducible modulo $ p $, in other words the primes $ p $ such that

$$ \left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = -1 $$

Quadratic reciprocity identifies these primes for us: they are precisely the primes that are $ 3 $ and $ 5 $ modulo $ 8 $. Thus, the primes that are $ 1 $ and $ 7 $ modulo $ 8 $ are split in $ \mathcal O_K $.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably a great proof; however, unfortunately I am unable to appreciate it due to the lack of knowledge. That's why I was expecting a more elementary approach.

Comment: Anything about this is bound to involve saying something about the class number of the field $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2}) $. If $ K $ is a quadratic number field with class number $ > 1 $ and $ p $ is a prime that splits into non-principal ideals in $ \mathcal O_K $, there will not be any element of $ \mathcal O_K $ having norm $ \pm p $. (Check that any such ideal would generate a prime lying above $ p $.)