# Does the equation $5+2y^2=x^2$ has solution $(x, y)$? Why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this kind of diophantine equation? How can we solve such equation?

Answer (score 1):

As for integer $a,a^2\equiv0,1,4\pmod5$

If $5\nmid y,y^2\equiv1,4\implies x^2=5+2y^2\equiv2,3\pmod5$

So, we need $5|y,y=5z$(say)

$\implies5+2(5z)^2=5(1+10z^2)\equiv5\pmod{5^2}$

So, we need $5|x\implies x^2\equiv0\pmod{5^2}$

But $5\not\equiv0\pmod{5^2}$

Comment: Why $5(1+10z^2)≡5(mod5^2)$?

Comment: @yashirq, $$5(1+10z^2)=5+25\cdot2z^2$$

Comment: Our answers and the question were downvoted at about the same time. As there is nothing wrong with either answer, perhaps the person who downvoted the question has downvoted two of the three answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a [Diophantine Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation). It is also known as [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation).

If $x^2-2y^2=5$, then $x$ must be odd and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
x^2&=(2k+1)^2\\
&=4k^2+4k+1\\
&=8\binom{k+1}{2}+1\\
&\equiv1\pmod8
\end{align}
$$
Then either $y$ is even and
$$
\begin{align}
2y^2
&=2(2k)^2\\
&\equiv0\pmod8
\end{align}
$$
or $y$ is odd and
$$
\begin{align}
2y^2
&=2(2k+1)^2\\
&=8k(k+1)+2\\
&\equiv2\pmod8
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, if $x^2-2y^2$ is odd, then
$$
x^2-2y^2\equiv\pm1\pmod8
$$

So we cannot have $x^2-2y^2=5$ since $5\not\equiv\pm1\pmod8$.

Comment: How can you derive the last step from mod 8?

Comment: I have incorporated that part into the earlier equations. It makes the argument shorter as well.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know why I got a downvote. I don't understand so I ask a question. What's the problem.

Comment: @yashirq: Questions without [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) often get downvoted and sometimes closed. If you add context, some people might take their downvotes away.

Comment: Well, I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If there were an integer solution $ (x, y) $, then reducing modulo $ 5 $ gives the result that $ x^2 \equiv 2y^2 \pmod{5} $. Since $ 2 $ is not a quadratic residue modulo $ 5 $, this implies $ x \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod{5} $, and thus $ x^2 - 2y^2 = 5 $ is divisible by $ 25 $, a contradiction. Thus, there are no such solutions.

See my answer to the question [The number of solutions to the equations $x^2-2y^2=\pm p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932082/the-number-of-solutions-to-the-equations-x2-2y2-pm-p/1932091#1932091) for a general answer to this problem.